# Convert consecutive Trues, to False python

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

Essentially, I want to convert consecutive duplicates of Trues, to False as the title suggests.

For example, say, i have an array of 0s and 1s

```
x = pd.Series([1,0,0,1,1])
```

should become:

```
y = pd.Series([0,0,0,0,1])
# where the 1st element of x becomes 0 since its not a consecutive
# and the 4th element becomes 0 because its the first instance of the consecutive duplicate
# And everything else should remain the same.
```

This can also apply to consecutives of more than two, Say i have a much longer array:
eg.

```
x = pd.Series([1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1])
```

becomes;

```
y = pd.Series([0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1])
```

Posts that i have searched are mostly either deleting consecutive duplicates, and does not retain the original length. In this case, it should retain the original length.

It is something like the following code:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] == x[i+1]:
        x[i] = True
    else:
       x[i] = False
```

but this gives me a never ending run. And does not accommodate consecutives of more than two.

Comment: How is this pandas?

Comment: @WDS you pandas array is 1D?

Comment: My original data is in pandas, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @WDS than give several rows of data or  data.head()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas solution - create `Series`, then consecutive groups by `shift` and `cumsum` and filter last `1` values in duplicates by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
s = pd.Series(x)
g = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()
s1 = (~g.duplicated(keep='last') & g.duplicated(keep=False) & s.eq(1)).astype(int)

print (s1.tolist())
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

EDIT:

For multiple columns use function:

```
x = pd.Series([1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1])
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':x, 'b':x})

def f(s):
    g = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()
    return (~g.duplicated(keep='last') & g.duplicated(keep=False) & s.eq(1)).astype(int)

df = df.apply(f)
print (df)
    a  b
0   0  0
1   0  0
2   0  0
3   0  0
4   0  0
5   1  1
6   0  0
7   0  0
8   1  1
9   0  0
10  0  0
11  0  0
12  0  0
13  1  1
14  0  0
15  0  0
16  0  0
17  0  0
18  0  0
19  0  0
20  1  1
```

Comment: I appreciate the help! I'm aware the question was meant for a pandas series, but how would this work in a DataFrame with N columns as this does not work with it (Computer will hang due to Memory overshooting with large DataFrame). It seems that the function ```duplicated()```  you have used only returns a series/array which causes that error........

Comment: Without using for loops, I initially thought to use ```apply()``` function on the dataframe but does not seem to work.

Comment: That's interesting, thank you again! And if you have time, out of curiosity, how is it that when i use it like this ```DataFrame.apply(duplicated, args = 'first')``` does not work?

Comment: hmm, I think here is necessary lambda function like `df = df.apply(lambda x: x.duplicated('first'))`

Answer (score 2):

Vanilla Python :

```
x = [1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]
counter = 0
for i, e in enumerate(x):
    if not e:
        counter = 0
        continue
    if not counter or (i < len(x) - 1 and x[i+1]):
        counter += 1
        x[i] = 0
print(x)
```

Prints :

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```